# Can you use mod_python with JBoss?

Tags: jboss, mod-python

Anyone know whether it is possible to put mod_python under JBoss like you can Apache HTTPD?  Given that JBoss has Tomcat inside it would seem to be a reasonable thing to do.

If not mod_python is there any python support under JBoss which will keep the interpreter in memory?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about running `mod_perl` in JBoss, but here are a couple of approaches you might want to consider:

#### Enabling CGI

You can enable CGI within tomcat. See [here](http://www.wellho.net/forum/Perl-Programming/Running-Perl-CGI-scripts-under-Apache-Tomcat.html) for an example?

#### Using jython

Java 6 has good support for running other languages within the JVM. One of these is the [jython](http://www.jython.org/Project/) variant of python?

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Fixed link

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [Jython](http://www.jython.org/Project/)? Tomcat is built in Java after all.